# Build for loop in one line and received wrong output which is a Nonetype

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to write a code in list comprehensions. However, I received nonetype when I do that.

Code:

```
a = ["I", "have", "something", "to", "buy"]
delete = ["I", "have"]

aa = [a.remove(x) for x in delete]
print(aa)
```

output:

```
[None, None]
```

Expected output:

```
["something", "to", "buy"]
```

Comment: You will have to print 'a' ... not 'aa'...

Comment: I see. Thank you sir. But what should I assign for the variable? Should I leave it aa? It will be a waste to the memory isnt it? Is there a smart way to use list comprehension without assign to any variable?

Comment: Found my way thank you

Comment: Else you could do as aa = [x for x in a if not x in delete]

Answer (score 1):

`list.remove` changes the list **inplace** and returns None. For example:

```
a = ["I", "have", "something", "to", "buy"]
print(a.remove("I")) # ['have', 'something', 'to', 'buy']
print(a) # None
```

If you really want to do this in one line, you can keep your code. While you don't need aa, just print a.

Comment: Thank you sir.  But what should I assign for the variable? Should I leave it aa? It will be a waste to the memory isnt it? Is there a smart way to use list comprehension without assign to any variable?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [comprehension if clause](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like:

#### Code:

```
aa = [x for x in a if x not in delete]
```

#### Test Code:

```
a = ["I", "have", "something", "to", "buy"]
delete = ["I", "have"]

aa = [x for x in a if x not in delete]
print(aa)
```

#### Results:

```
['something', 'to', 'buy']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try print(a) instead of print (aa)

When you do a.remove(x), it removes it from the array'a'.

```
  a = ["I", "have", "something", "to", "buy"]
  delete = ["I", "have"]

  aa = [a.remove(x) for x in delete]
  print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding the usage of 'remove' and/or comprehension list.

```
aList.remove(item)
```

modify the variable "aList" itself and does not return anything(that's why you're getting only None items).
What you're doing is iterating through every delete's item, and calling remove. 
Actually, your a list should be the result you want after creating the aa list :

```
a = ["I", "have", "something", "to", "buy"]
delete = ["I", "have"]

aa = [a.remove(x) for x in delete]

a  ["something", "to", "buy"]

aa  [None,None]
```

A proper way to obtain the intended result without modifying the initial a list could be:

```
aa=[word for word in a if not word in delete]
aa  ["something", "to", "buy"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something similar to this conceptually with `filterfalse`

```
from itertools import filterfalse

aa = list(filterfalse(lambda x: x in delete, a))
print(aa)
# ['something', 'to', 'buy']
```